Flask route not working when using docker-code.server
I use docker-code-server to edit and run code (https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-code-server)
version: "2.1"
services:
  code-server:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/code-server:latest
    container_name: code-server
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx #optional
      - DEFAULT_WORKSPACE=/config/workspace #optional
      - DOCKER_MODS=linuxserver/mods:code-server-python3
    volumes:
      - D:\docker_images\linux_vscode_image\config:/config
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
      - 8501:8501
      - 5000:5000
    restart: unless-stopped

However when I am trying to Learn Flask (using blueprints), any routes I create do not work as expected
@main_blueprint.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

This route is only accessible when I navigate to "http://localhost:8443/proxy/5000/about",  but any redirects (eg from a link) point to http://localhost:8443/about which is not found.
I am not so knowledgeable that I understand the issue, so despite trying many things such as blueprint url_redirects, middleware etc... I have not found a working solution.
Can anyone point me to what I have to do to get the Flask app to redirect correctly?
Or what I have to do with the docker configuration?

For development, Flask runs on port 5000.  It looks like you're opening port 5000 so navigating there should work. If you have a proxy on 8443 you should check the configuration of whatever server is running there and remove the /proxy route. Typically for production you want something like gunicorn or uwsgi (and you would close 5000 completely).
